# Jekyll-admin fails with NoMethodError - undefined method `config_files'

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Using Mac M1 OS Big Sur 11.5.2

home-brew installed ruby 3.1.0, Jekyll 4.2.1

Git repo at https://github.com/amitaskitchen/amitaskitchen.github.io

When I add `jekyll-admin` to `Gemfile`... `bundle exec jekyll serve` comes up fine, but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:4000/admin - I see the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `config_files'
```

Google'd the error and tried a bunch of things... but could not get rid of the error.
Any help / pointers would be appreciated.

Here is the complete error:

```
Doing `require 'backports'` is deprecated and will not load any backport in the next major release.
Require just the needed backports instead, or 'backports/latest'.
Configuration file: /Users/agautam/workspace/amitaskitchen.github.io/_config.yml
 Theme Config file: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/popfolio-0.1.0/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/agautam/workspace/amitaskitchen.github.io
       Destination: /Users/agautam/workspace/amitaskitchen.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.211 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/agautam/workspace/amitaskitchen.github.io'
  JekyllAdmin mode: production
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
2022-02-26 14:53:34 - NoMethodError - undefined method `config_files' for {"author"=>{"name"=>"Matt Shultz", "email"=>"matt@shultz.dev"}, "social"=>{"name"=>"David Darnes", "links"=>{"github"=>"popshift", "linkedin"=>"matt-shultz-85605ba6"}}, "lang"=>"en-US", "title"=>"Amitas Kitchen", "header_title"=>"PF", "css_inline"=>false, "avatar"=>"assets/avatar.png", "intro"=>{"main"=>"Hi, my name is Popshift", "sub"=>"I made this theme for you"}, "footer_message"=>"#coolhashtag ", "skills"=>[{"skill"=>"Javascript", "svg_id"=>"js-square"}, {"skill"=>"HTML", "svg_id"=>"html5"}, {"skill"=>"CSS", "svg_id"=>"css3-alt"}, {"skill"=>"React", "svg_id"=>"react"}, {"skill"=>"Python", "svg_id"=>"python"}, {"skill"=>"Node.JS", "svg_id"=>"node-js"}], "projects"=>[{"title"=>"Project 1 Title", "description"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url"=>"#", "image"=>"https://via.placeholder.com/250x200", "featured"=>true, "tags"=>["html", "css", "javascript"]}, {"title"=>"Project 2 Title", "description"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url"=>"#", "image"=>"https://via.placeholder.com/250x200", "featured"=>true, "tags"=>["html", "css", "javascript"]}, {"title"=>"Project 3 Title", "description"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", "url"=>"#", "image"=>"https://via.placeholder.com/250x200", "featured"=>true, "tags"=>["html", "css", "javascript"]}], "source"=>"/Users/agautam/workspace/amitaskitchen.github.io/", "destination"=>"/Users/agautam/workspace/amitaskitchen.github.io/_site", "collections_dir"=>"", "cache_dir"=>".jekyll-cache", "plugins_dir"=>"_plugins", "layouts_dir"=>"_layouts", "data_dir"=>"_data", "includes_dir"=>"_includes", "collections"=>{"posts"=>{"output"=>true, "permalink"=>"/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title:output_ext"}}, "safe"=>false, "include"=>[".htaccess"], "exclude"=>[".sass-cache", ".jekyll-cache", "gemfiles", "Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock", "node_modules", "vendor/bundle/", "vendor/cache/", "vendor/gems/", "vendor/ruby/"], "keep_files"=>[".git", ".svn"], "encoding"=>"utf-8", "markdown_ext"=>"markdown,mkdown,mkdn,mkd,md", "strict_front_matter"=>false, "show_drafts"=>nil, "limit_posts"=>0, "future"=>false, "unpublished"=>false, "whitelist"=>[], "plugins"=>["jekyll-feed", "jekyll-admin"], "markdown"=>"kramdown", "highlighter"=>"rouge", "lsi"=>false, "excerpt_separator"=>"\n\n", "incremental"=>false, "detach"=>false, "port"=>"4000", "host"=>"127.0.0.1", "baseurl"=>"", "show_dir_listing"=>false, "permalink"=>"date", "paginate_path"=>"/page:num", "timezone"=>nil, "quiet"=>false, "verbose"=>false, "defaults"=>[], "liquid"=>{"error_mode"=>"warn", "strict_filters"=>false, "strict_variables"=>false}, "kramdown"=>{"auto_ids"=>true, "toc_levels"=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "entity_output"=>"as_char", "smart_quotes"=>"lsquo,rsquo,ldquo,rdquo", "input"=>"GFM", "hard_wrap"=>false, "guess_lang"=>true, "footnote_nr"=>1, "show_warnings"=>false, "syntax_highlighter"=>"rouge", "syntax_highlighter_opts"=>{"default_lang"=>"plaintext", "guess_lang"=>true}, "coderay"=>{}}, "email"=>"your-email@example.com", "description"=>"Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.", "url"=>"http://localhost:4000", "theme"=>"popfolio", "jekyll_admin"=>{"hidden_links"=>["configuration"]}, "livereload_port"=>35729, "serving"=>true, "watch"=>true}:Hash

        sanitized_path configuration.config_files(overrides).first
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^:
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-admin-0.11.0/lib/jekyll-admin/server/configuration.rb:47:in `configuration_path'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-admin-0.11.0/lib/jekyll-admin/server/configuration.rb:34:in `parsed_configuration'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-admin-0.11.0/lib/jekyll-admin/server/configuration.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Server>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1611:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1611:in `block in compile!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:994:in `route_eval'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1015:in `block in process_route'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `catch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `process_route'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:973:in `block in route!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `route!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1085:in `block in dispatch!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1082:in `dispatch!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `block in call!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `call!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:895:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.5/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.5/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.5/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.5/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.5/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.5/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:182:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2013:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `block in call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1787:in `synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webrick-1.7.0/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webrick-1.7.0/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webrick-1.7.0/lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the presence of a config file in the theme-gem you're using.
Therefore instruct Jekyll to *ignore* the theme-config by adding the following to your **config file**:

```
ignore_theme_config: true
```